# Variable not updating correctly when prompted

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to setup a prompt that takes user input and then calls a query on the backend. When I enter the code the first time it gives me a value of 'null' but then when I enter it again it gives me the correct value.

```
updateStatus() {
  let update = {
    "status_id": this.status_id
  }

  this.$root.$dialog.prompt({
    title: "Update status to: ",
    body: 'Enter a status id number: 1 - open, 450 - In Progress, 900 - Closed'
  })
  .then(dialog => {
    this.status_id = dialog.data
    if(this.status_id == 1 || this.status_id == 450 || this.status_id == 900) {
      this.$http.put(`/someurl/?quote_number=${this.query_number}`, update).then(res => {
        this.$root.$dialog.alert(`You entered status: ${this.status_id}`)
        if(res.data.error) {
          this.$root.updateError(res.data.error)
        } else {
          this.$root.updateSuccess(res.data.message)
        }
      })
    } else {
        this.$root.$dialog.alert("You entered an invalid status code")
        this.status_id = null
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.$root.updateError(error)
  })
}
```